# Dependent dropdown not working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

this is my first time on this site so I'll cut to chase.

I've been working on a fixed assets control web system using PHP, AJAX, jquery and MySQL as database (the project structure was made by following the tutorial from this website: https://www.itechempires.com/2016/07/pdo-crud-operations-using-php-bootstrap/ ), where such items are registered along with the categories to which each asset belongs, the transactions made by the users within the company and the reports generated by each transaction.

Currently I'm stuck with the dropdowns since I tried anything I could to make them work but without the results I've been looking for, which is:
in a modal there's a form where an asset is going to be added with its related information, two of those details are categories and subcategories which are handled by dependent dropdowns, the dropdown regarding to subcategories will be displayed once a category is selected.

The code snippets will be up for review which will be focused on the ones related to the dropdowns:

**Tables**

**grupo (group or category)**

- id_grp (group id,autoincremented, not visible by the user)
- codigo_grp (code)
- nombre_grp (name)

**subgeupo (subgroup or subcategory)**

- id_sgrp (subgroup id, autoincremented, not visible by the user)
- codigo_sgrp (code)
- nombre_sgrp (name)
- vidaUtil_sgrp (useful life)
- id_grp (group id, foreign key)

**libAF.php: Contains all queries for crud operations**

```
    /* 
    * Get group's id and name
    *
    * @return $id_grp, $nombre_grp
    * */
    public function populateSelGrp()
    {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id_grp, nombre_grp FROM grupo");
        $query->execute();
        $data = array();
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /* 
    * Get sub-group's id and name
    *
    * @return $id_grp, $nombre_grp
    * */
    public function populateSelSgrp($id_grp)
    {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM subgrupo WHERE id_grp = :id_grp");
        $query->bindParam("id_grp", $id_grp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        $data = array();
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

**populateSelGrp.php: loads the categories on to the parent dropdown**

```
<?php

require 'libAF.php';

$data = "";

$object = new CRUD();

$grupos = $object->populateSelGrp();

$data .= '<select id="select_grp" class="form-control" onchange="populateSelSgrp()">';
$data .= '<option value="0" disabled selected>Escoja grupo</option>';    
if (count($grupos) > 0) {
    foreach ($grupos as $grupo) {
        $data .= '<option id="selected_grp" value="' . $grupo['id_grp'] . '"> ' . $grupo['nombre_grp'] . '</option>';
    }
}
else
{
    $data .= '<option>No hay opciones disponibles</option>';
}

$data .= '</select>';

echo $data;

?>
```

**populateSelSgrp.php: loads the subcategories on to the child dropdown**

```
<?php

require 'libAF.php';

if (isset($_POST['id_grp']) && isset($_POST['id_grp']) != "") {
    $id_grp = $_POST['id_grp'];
    $data = "";

    $object = new CRUD();

    $subgrupos = $object->populateSelSgrp($id_grp);

    $data .= '<label for="select_sgrp">Sub-grupo</label>';
    $data .= '<select id="select_sgrp" class="form-control">';
    $data .= '<option value="0" disabled selected>Escoja sub-grupo</option>';

    if (count($subgrupos) > 0) {
        foreach ($subgrupos as $subgrupo) {    
            $data .= '<option value="' . $subgrupo['id_sgrp'] . '"> ' . $subgrupo['nombre_sgrp'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $data .= '<option>No hay opciones disponibles</option>';        
    }

    $data .= '</select>';

    echo $data;
}

?>
```

**scptAF.js: Contains the scripts needed to make the inputs work**

```
function populateSelGrp(){        
$.get("ajax/activoFijo/populateSelGrp.php", {
},
    function (data, status) {
//load options to dropdown list
        $(".option_grp").html(data);
    }
);
}

function populateSelSgrp(id_grp){
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/activoFijo/populateSelSgrp.php",
    method: "POST",
    data:{id_grp: id_grp},
    success:function(data){
        $(".option_sgrp").html(data);
    }
})            
}
```

**activos.php (assets): visible page where the user adds, removes or updates an asset.**

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="select_grp">Grupo</label>
     <div class="option_grp"></div>
 </div>         
 <div class="form-group">
      <div class="option_sgrp"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution for this mess, was a little code I had to add to the javaScript file to send the id to the second dropdown. Although I finally fixed my problem, I'd like to see other suggestions on how to tackle this problem.

Here's my snippet

**scptAF.js**

```
function populateSelGrp() {
$.get("ajax/activoFijo/populateSelGrp.php", {
},
    function (data, status) {
//load options to dropdown list
        $(".option_grp").html(data);
    }
);
}

function changeGrpId(){
var id_grp = document.getElementById("select_grp").value;
populateSelSgrp(id_grp);
}

function populateSelSgrp(id_grp) {
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/activoFijo/populateSelSgrp.php",
    method: "POST",
    data:{id_grp: id_grp},
    success:function(data){
        $(".option_sgrp").html(data);
    }
})
}
```