# Edit form elements (dropdown and input date) are not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, bootstrap-4

I'm still struggling with the same project and this time is with the edit form (opened through a modal) which uses 8 text fields, 4 dropdowns (2 are the same dynamic dropdowns I posted on my previous [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042958/dependent-dropdown-not-working-correctly/)) and a single standard input type date where the data must be loaded from the database after selecting a record from the grid (which is a simple html table) to edit.

I don't know if I've missed anything or if it was something else I have to apply into the code, so please let me know your thoughts.

I'll post the codes down below for review:

**Table "activofijo" (fixed asset)**

- id_AF (id)
- codigo_AF (user inserted code)
- descripción_AF (description)
- id_prov (id from the providers table)
- id_td (id from document type table)
- numeroDocumento_AF (document number)
- fechaDocumento_AF (document date)
- valorAdquisicion_AF (asset's purchase value)
- vidaUtil_AF (asset's useful life)
- valorActual_AF (asset's current value)
- vidaUtilMes_AF (asset's useful life in months for depreciation calculation)
- id_grp (id from categories table)
- id_sgrp (id from subcategories table)

**libAF.php**

```
    public function detailsAF($id_AF)
    {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM activofijo WHERE id_AF = :id_AF");
        $query->bindParam("id_AF", $id_AF, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        return json_encode($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }
```

**detailsAF.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id_AF']) && isset($_POST['id_AF']) != "") {
    require 'libAF.php';
    $id_AF = $_POST['id_AF'];

    $object = new CRUD();

    echo $object->detailsAF($id_AF);
}
?>
```

**scptAF.js**

```
function getAFDetails(id_AF) {
loadUpdDropDowns();
// Add asset's ID to the hidden field
$("#hidden_AF_id").val(id_AF);
$.post("ajax/activoFijo/detailsAF.php", {
    id_AF: id_AF
},
    function (data, status) {
        // PARSE json data
        var activofijo = JSON.parse(data);
        // Assign existing values to the modal popup fields
        $("#upd_codigo_AF").val(activofijo.codigo_AF);
        $("#upd_descripcion_AF").val(activofijo.descripcion_AF);
        $("#upd_select_prov").val(activofijo.id_prov);
        $("#upd_select_td").val(activofijo.id_td);
        $("#upd_numeroDocumento_AF").val(activofijo.numeroDocumento_AF);
        $("#upd_fechaDocumento_AF").val(activofijo.fechaDocumento_AF);
        $("#upd_valorAdquisicion_AF").val(activofijo.valorAdquisicion_AF);
        $("#upd_vidaUtil_AF").val(activofijo.vidaUtil_AF);
        $("#upd_valorActual_AF").val(activofijo.valorActual_AF);
        $("#upd_vidaUtilMes_AF").val(activofijo.vidaUtilMes_AF);
        $("#upd_select_grp").val(activofijo.id_grp);
        $("#upd_select_sgrp").val(activofijo.id_sgrp);
    }
);
// Open modal popup
$("#update_AF_modal").modal("show");
}

//sync asset's original cost textfield with the salvage value hidden field to set a
//starting value for depreciation calculation

function syncValorAF()
{
var n1 = document.getElementById('valorAdquisicion_AF');
var n2 = document.getElementById('valorActual_AF');
n2.value = n1.value;
}

//sync asset's useful life textfield with the useful life in months hidden field to set a
//starting value for depreciation calculation

function syncVidaUtilAF()
{
var v1 = document.getElementById('vidaUtil_AF');
var v2 = document.getElementById('vidaUtilMes_AF');
v2.value = v1.value * 12;
}
```

**activos.php**

```
<!-- Modal - Update details -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="update_AF_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar nuevo activo</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <h5>Datos generales del activo</h5>                            
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="upd_codigo_AF">Codigo del activo</label>
                        <input type="text" id="upd_codigo_AF" placeholder="Codigo del activo" class="form-control" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="upd_descripcion_AF">Descripción</label>
                        <textarea id="upd_descripcion_AF" placeholder="Descripción" class="form-control" rows="3" cols="30" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="upd_select_prov">Proveedor</label>
                        <div class="upd_option_prov"></div>
                    </div>
                    <br>     
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <h5>Datos de adquisición</h5>
                    </div>                           
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="upd_select_td">Tipo de documento</label>
                        <div class="upd_option_td"></div>
                    </div>                 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="upd_numeroDocumento_AF">N° de documento</label>
                        <input type="number" id="upd_numeroDocumento_AF" placeholder="N° de documento" class="form-control" required/>
                    </div>                       
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="upd_fechaDocumento_AF">Fecha de documento</label>
                        <input type="date" id="upd_fechaDocumento_AF" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" class="form-control" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="upd_valorAdquisicion_AF">Valor del activo</label>
                        <input type="number" id="upd_valorAdquisicion_AF" placeholder="Valor del activo" class="form-control" onkeyup="syncValorAF()" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="upd_vidaUtil_AF">Vida util</label>
                        <input type="number" id="upd_vidaUtil_AF" placeholder="Vida util" class="form-control" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="number" id="upd_valorActual_AF" class="form-control" hidden readonly/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="number" id="upd_vidaUtilMes_AF" class="form-control" hidden readonly/>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <h5>Clasificación del activo</h5>
                    </div>                            
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="upd_select_grp">Grupo</label>
                        <div class="upd_option_grp"></div>
                    </div>         
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="upd_option_sgrp"></div>
                    </div>         
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="updateAF()">Agregar</button>
                    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_AF_id">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- // Modal -->
```

PS: I apologize in advance if I have bad grammar, and BTW the code used to populate the non dependent dropdowns is the same from the previous problem with the exception that they don't have an onchange function.

**Edit**

I forgot to add what the problem was, the problem I'm having is that when I'm opening the modal to edit, I can't get the selected options loaded into their respective dropdowns, and the same goes for the date. I Also forgot to add the response file for the grid to check how the data is viewed by the user along with it's respective js script.
My apologies.

**readAF.php**

```
<?php

require 'libAF.php';
$data = "";

$object = new CRUD();

// Design initial table header
$data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Código del activo</td>
                        <td>Descripción</td>
                        <td>Nombre del proveedor</td>
                        <td>Tipo de documento</td>
                        <td>N° de documento</td>
                        <td>Fecha del documento</td>
                        <td>Valor de adquisición</td>
                        <td>Vida util</td>
                        <td>Valor actual</td>
                        <td>Grupo del activo</td>
                        <td>Sub-grupo del activo</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>';


$activos = $object->readAF();

if (count($activos) > 0) {
foreach ($activos as $activo) {
    $fechaDocumento_AF = date_create($activo['fechaDocumento_AF']);
    $data .= '<tr>
        <td>' . $activo['codigo_AF'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $activo['descripcion_AF'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $activo['nombre_prov'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $activo['nombre_td'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $activo['numeroDocumento_AF'] . '</td>
        <td>' . date_format($fechaDocumento_AF, 'd-m-Y') . '</td>
        <td>' . $activo['valorAdquisicion_AF'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $activo['vidaUtil_AF'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $activo['valorActual_AF'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $activo['nombre_grp'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $activo['nombre_sgrp'] . '</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button onclick="getAFDetails(' . $activo['id_AF'] . ')" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</button>
                <button onclick="deleteAF(' . $activo['id_AF'] . ')" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>';
}
} else {
// records not found
$data .= '<tr><td colspan="6">No hay datos disponibles</td></tr>';
}

$data .= '</table>';

echo $data;

?>
```

**scptAF.php**

```
// READ records
function readRecords() {
$.get("ajax/activoFijo/readAF.php", {
}, function (data, status) {
    $(".records_content").html(data);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem myself (again), and although is kinda buggy, it works as expected. Anyway, I'll upload the code here for review and please share your feedback.

**libAF.php**

```
    public function detailsAF($id_AF)
    {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM activofijo WHERE id_AF = :id_AF");
        $query->bindParam("id_AF", $id_AF, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        return json_encode($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }

       public function readAF()
    {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT activofijo.id_AF, activofijo.codigo_AF, activofijo.descripcion_AF, proveedores.nombre_prov, tipodocumento.nombre_td, activofijo.numeroDocumento_AF, activofijo.fechaDocumento_AF, activofijo.valorAdquisicion_AF, activofijo.vidaUtil_AF, activofijo.valorActual_AF, grupo.nombre_grp, subgrupo.nombre_sgrp, activofijo.estado_AF FROM activofijo INNER JOIN proveedores ON activofijo.id_prov = proveedores.id_prov INNER JOIN tipodocumento ON activofijo.id_td = tipodocumento.id_td INNER JOIN grupo ON activofijo.id_grp = grupo.id_grp INNER JOIN subgrupo ON activofijo.id_sgrp = subgrupo.id_sgrp");
        $query->execute();
        $data = array();
        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

**detailsAF.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id_AF']) && isset($_POST['id_AF']) != "") {
    require 'libAF.php';
    $id_AF = $_POST['id_AF']; 
    $object = new CRUD();
    echo $object->detailsAF($id_AF);
}
?>
```

**readAF.php**

```
<?php
require 'libAF.php';
$data = "";
$object = new CRUD();
// Design initial table header
$data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Código del activo</td>
                            <td>Descripción</td>
                            <td>Nombre del proveedor</td>
                            <td>Tipo de documento</td>
                            <td>N° de documento</td>
                            <td>Fecha del documento</td>
                            <td>Valor de adquisición</td>
                            <td>Vida util</td>
                            <td>Valor actual</td>
                            <td>Grupo del activo</td>
                            <td>Sub-grupo del activo</td>
                            <td>Estado</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>';
$activos = $object->readAF();
if (count($activos) > 0) {
    foreach ($activos as $activo) {
        $fechaDocumento_AF = date_create($activo['fechaDocumento_AF']);
        $data .= '<tr>
            <td>' . $activo['codigo_AF'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $activo['descripcion_AF'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $activo['nombre_prov'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $activo['nombre_td'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $activo['numeroDocumento_AF'] . '</td>
            <td>' . date_format($fechaDocumento_AF, 'd-m-Y') . '</td>
            <td>' . $activo['valorAdquisicion_AF'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $activo['vidaUtil_AF'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $activo['valorActual_AF'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $activo['nombre_grp'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $activo['nombre_sgrp'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $activo['estado_AF'] . '</td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button onclick="getAFDetails(' . $activo['id_AF'] . ')" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</button>
                    <button onclick="deleteAF(' . $activo['id_AF'] . ')" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>';
    }
} else {
// records not found
    $data .= '<tr><td colspan="6">No hay datos disponibles</td></tr>';
}
$data .= '</table>';
echo $data;
?>
```

**scriptAF.js**

```
// Dynamic dropdown samples
function populateUpdSelGrp(callback){
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/activoFijo/populateSelGrp.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(grupos){
        //load options to dropdown list
        grupos = JSON.parse(grupos);
        $("#upd_select_grp").empty();
        $("#upd_select_grp").append('<option value="" disabled>Escoja grupo</option>');
        grupos.forEach(function(grupo){
            $("#upd_select_grp").append('<option value="'+grupo.id_grp+'">'+grupo.nombre_grp+'</option>');
            callback();
        })
    }
})
}
function populateUpdSelSgrp(callback){
$("#upd_select_grp").change(function(){
    var id_grp = $("#upd_select_grp").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/activoFijo/populateSelSgrp.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: "id_grp=" + id_grp,
        success: function(subgrupos){
            //load options to dropdown list
            subgrupos = JSON.parse(subgrupos);
            $("#upd_select_sgrp").empty();
            $("#upd_select_sgrp").append('<option value="" disabled>Escoja sub-grupo</option>');
            subgrupos.forEach(function(subgrupo){
                $("#upd_select_sgrp").append('<option value="'+subgrupo.id_sgrp+'">'+subgrupo.nombre_sgrp+'</option>');
                callback();
            })
        }
    })
})
// !Dynamic dropdown samples
}
function getAFDetails(id_AF) {
// Add asset's ID to the hidden field
$("#hidden_id_AF").val(id_AF);
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/activoFijo/detailsAF.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: "id_AF="+id_AF,
    success:function(data, status){
        console.log(data);
        // PARSE json data
        var activofijo = JSON.parse(data);
        // Assign existing values to the modal popup fields
        $("#upd_codigo_AF").val(activofijo.codigo_AF);
        $("#upd_descripcion_AF").val(activofijo.descripcion_AF);
        populateUpdSelProv(function(){
            $("#upd_select_prov").val(activofijo.id_prov);
        });
        populateUpdSelTD(function(){
            $("#upd_select_td").val(activofijo.id_td);
        });
        $("#upd_numeroDocumento_AF").val(activofijo.numeroDocumento_AF);
        $("#upd_fechaDocumento_AF").val(activofijo.fechaDocumento_AF);
        $("#upd_valorAdquisicion_AF").val(activofijo.valorAdquisicion_AF);
        $("#upd_vidaUtil_AF").val(activofijo.vidaUtil_AF);
        $("#upd_valorActual_AF").val(activofijo.valorActual_AF);
        populateUpdSelGrp(function(){
            $("#upd_select_grp").val(activofijo.id_grp);
            $("#upd_select_grp").trigger("change");
        });
        populateUpdSelSgrp(function(){
            $("#upd_select_sgrp").val(activofijo.id_sgrp);
        });
        $("#upd_estado_AF").val(activofijo.estado_AF);
    }
})
// Open modal popup
$("#update_AF_modal").modal("show");
}
```

**activos.php**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="update_AF_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Actualizar activo</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-top-center">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <h5>Datos generales del activo</h5>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="upd_codigo_AF">Codigo del activo</label>
                            <input type="text" id="upd_codigo_AF" placeholder="Codigo del activo" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="upd_descripcion_AF">Descripción</label>
                            <textarea id="upd_descripcion_AF" placeholder="Descripción" class="form-control" rows="3" cols="30" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="upd_select_prov">Proveedor</label>
                            <select name="upd_select_prov" class="form-control" id="upd_select_prov">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-left-col">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <h5>Datos de adquisición</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="upd_select_td">Tipo de documento</label>
                            <select name="upd_select_td" class="form-control" id="upd_select_td">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="upd_numeroDocumento_AF">N° de documento</label>
                            <input type="number" id="upd_numeroDocumento_AF" placeholder="N° de documento" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="upd_fechaDocumento_AF">Fecha de documento</label>
                            <input type="date" id="upd_fechaDocumento_AF" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="upd_valorAdquisicion_AF">Valor del activo</label>
                            <input type="number" id="upd_valorAdquisicion_AF" placeholder="Valor del activo" class="form-control" onkeyup="syncUpdValorAF()" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="upd_vidaUtil_AF">Vida util</label>
                            <input type="number" id="upd_vidaUtil_AF" placeholder="Vida util" class="form-control"  required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="number" id="upd_valorActual_AF" class="form-control" hidden readonly/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="number" id="upd_vidaUtilMes_AF" class="form-control" hidden readonly/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-right-col">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <h5>Clasificación del activo</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="upd_select_grp">Grupo</label>
                            <select name="upd_select_grp" class="form-control" id="upd_select_grp">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="upd_select_sgrp">Sub-grupo</label>
                            <select name="upd_select_sgrp" class="form-control" id="upd_select_sgrp">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <h5>Estado del activo</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="upd_estado_AF">Estado</label>
                            <select name="upd_estado_AF" class="form-control" id="upd_estado_AF">
                                <option value="Entregado">Entregado</option>
                                <option value="Disponible">Disponible</option>
                                <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="updateAFDetails()">Actualizar</button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_id_AF">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```